# Administrator Rights for a set of code

Tags: passwords

I am developing a program for Windows 7 Enterprise Edition that will be used in a corporate environment. The application will automatically fix certain errors as soon as the user selects the application name, chooses the symptom or error message and clicking on the fix button.

The idea behind is to decrease the amount of calls we receive at the IT Service Desk (the company's personal Call Centre for IT Issues) and at the same time assist the end user by resolving the issue within a minute (versus waiting on the phone for up to 15 minutes or more).

I'm not yet allowed to upload an image of the application, but imagine a smallish Windows form with 2 columns, application name and symptom. The user will choose the application's name, click on the error message and click on the FIX button. This basically automates whatever we as IT Techs would do manually.

The problem I'm facing is that some of the code is supposed to be executed with administrator rights, e.g. Stop and Start a given service, adding registry entries for the local machine, etc.

Given the fact that none of the users will be allowed to have elevated rights and the fact that they need to use this application as a sort of "self-help" alternative without the need to call the IT Service Desk, is there a way to give a set of code "administrator permissions"? The application should NOT request the user to enter ANY passwords.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, the standard way of doing this is to create a service that runs with administrator rights and takes RPC calls from an unprivileged user application.  MSDN calls this the [operating system service model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Another option is the [elevated task model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550644%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); again, see MSDN for more details.

As with any security-related software, don't trust the client.  (In this case, "the client" is the unprivileged user application.) If your administrator service or task takes commands like "execute support procedure A," then you're probably okay. If your administrator service takes commands like "start arbitrary service" or "write arbitrary registry key," then a malicious client could use it to effectively have full admin rights.

**To elaborate**: The client is under the control of the end user, which means that a malicious user can do anything they want to with it, including replacing it with a hacked or modified client that issues whatever commands they want.

If clicking "AppName" "ErrorMessage" "FIX" results in the client sending a "Fix AppName ErrorMessage" RPC call to the server, then you're fine. Even a malicious client can't do anything that a well-behaved client could.

Suppose, however, that the RPC interface is lower-level and the list of fixes is managed by the client.  Suppose that clicking "AppName" "ErrorMessage" "FIX" results in the client saying, "I know how to fix that. Service, write registry key `AppName\A` and restart service `App Service B`."  In that case, a mailcious client could say, "Service, write registry key `CriticalWindowsSecurityKey\C` and restart service `Evil Hacker Service D`." That would be bad.

Comment: Parden my ignorance, but I'm a newbie when it comes to programming. The registry entry and the service to be stopped and started will not harm anything on the PC. I'm not sure how the user or the app can do anthing "maliciously". There is only one button to click on that is supposed to perform the task. So click on "AppName" in listbox 1, then "ErrorMessage" in listbox 2, then click on the FIX button to execute the code.

Comment: @WillemVoigt - I've added some more details. Does this make sense?

Comment: Is there a way I could share  my code with you. I have a bit of an understanding of what you wrote about. I think if you could see the interface of the app and view the code, you would be able to clarify things more for me. Again. Sorry. I'm basically teaching myself C#...only ever did a very basic Delphi course in college :)

Comment: @WillemVoigt - Unfortunately, I really don't have time to provide more detailed help right now, and C# and Windows services aren't my areas of expertise either. [Phil W.'s answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/257288/3223) has some very good details, and the [chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) can be a good place for more interactive Q&A, once you earn a bit more reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Put the "useful" stuff into a Windows Service and install that onto the user's machines.   Windows Services *implicitly* run "elevated".
Use your favourite cross-process communication method to send "requests" to the service from your user-visible utility program.  (I still favour using something based on TCP, if only because Windows Security hasn't poked its nose fully into those yet and you *don't* want the Security Contexts mixing here).  If you're really lucky, this might even work remotely, so your support staff have the option to run things on users' behalf, so long as the Service is running.  Why have two ways of doing the same thing?

The Service can only process requests that the user-visible, client application knows to ask about (there *should not* be a free-format "here's a DOS command; run it" option!) but the user never sees or interacts directly with the Service; just the visible, utility program.

When you need to add *new* functionality, deploy a new version of the Service executable - OK, fiddly, because you have to shut it down before you can update the physical file, but still perfectly possible - or deploy all the requestable "functions" as Dlls that the service loads at run-time (just remember to include a "request" to *unload* all of the "request" dlls!)

Comment: Thank you. I'll study up om creating a Windows Service app and take it from there.